# Variable name in calling scope

Tags: r

I have a function that takes a single variable as its argument:

```
calling_variable_name <- function(var) {
   ...
}

callling_variable_name(calling_variable)
```

What the function is supposed to do is return the name of the variable the function is called with, `calling_variable` in this case. I know I can get the name of the variable within the function using `quote()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never really asked a question - but the function that accomplishes what you'd like to do is `substitute()`:

```
calling_variable_name <- function(var){
  return(substitute(var))
}

calling_variable = 2
calling_variable_name(calling_variable)
# prints literal: calling_variable (and not 2)
```